# Can't make my computer a "trusted PC" with windows live account on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I upgraded to Windows 8 RTM a few weeks ago and yesterday I attempted to create a Windows Store account using my bizspark token.  I get the message: "We don't recognize the computer you're using".

This is the same computer I've been using..  As I understand it I was supposed to get an email to confirm this as a new trusted computer when I upgraded.  I never did.  I have valid emails accounts and a phone number associated with my windows Live account.

In trying to figure it out I "deleted" the listed trusted computers, so that will happen in 30 days but if I click the Cancel the deletion I am taken to a screen that says:

"Use your existing security info to help us make sure this is you. How can we contact you? ", with the only option available being "Use my trusted PC".

I saw somewhere in some forum that Windows Essentials is supposed to help, I downloaded it and ran wlstartup.exe and if I remember correctly I had the option to make this a trusted PC.  It made no difference, I'm still not trusted . If I rerun wlstartup it just gives me a dialog that says "Connect your favorite Services" with a Linked In logo.  I tried it with no other apps running and logged out of Live and messenger.  The file version of wlstartup is: 16.4.3503.728

I've tried devices.live.com  , click the "add this computer" link and it takes me to the Essentials download page, which, as mentioned, I've already downloaded and ran.

So basically, I need to make my computer trusted ( again ) so I can get a Windows Store account, and have no idea how.

Anyone else have this problem?

Thansk,
Craig

Comment: This has to be the single most frustrating thing about windows 8 so far.

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe reinstall windows 8. You need to trust the new PC from the old install, which is impossible, so frustratingly you have to wait 30 days before you can delete the old install and add the new trusted PC.

http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/security/windows-live-trusted-computer-143668

Comment: Argh, this is _so_ not a solution (even though it probably is).